# Vuetify datatable How to override the styling

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to change my font-size, padding, and margin. I am not able to change the padding and margin of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `!important` suffix after your property value in CSS.

For Example :
If the Default style of your `h1 element is :

```css
h1{
  color: red;
}
```

You would need to override the default color with the color you want (red in this case) using `!important`.
Your code to look like this :

```css
h1{
  color: red!important;
}
```

I hope it works!